# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet'

Tags: c#

I have the following class. That I move over from another program to create a ClassLibary.

I'm getting the error message below anywhere where I have wb.Worksheeet

Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The class works in the original program.  I've added the reference Inereop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using _Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

 public class Excel
    {
        string path = "";
        _Application excel = new _Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb;
        Worksheet ws;

        public Excel()
        {

        }

        public Excel(string path, int sheet)
        {
            this.path = path;
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
            ws = wb.Worksheets[sheet];
        }

        public void Open(string path, int sheet)
        {
            this.path = path;
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
            ws = wb.Worksheets[sheet];
        }

        public void CreateNewFile()
        {
            this.wb = excel.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
            this.ws = wb.Worksheets[1];
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add explicit type conversions with following style:

```
ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[sheet];
```

With explicit conversion you have to be sure of target type. [In documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbookclass.worksheets?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_WorkbookClass_Worksheets) it is stated that Worksheets-collection can contain both Charts and Worksheet objects.

Comment: Yes, this will take care of the issue but what I'm trying to figure out is way does it work without the explicit type on my original program.

Comment: @user3537446 maybe older version of Interop-dll referenced on your another program?

Answer (score 0):

In your `csproj` update your `Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"` to embed the interop types. This will allow the use of `dynamic` instead of plain `object` types.

```xml
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel">
  <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll</HintPath>
  <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
</Reference>
```